# How can I create a json structure using all the @api.route paths

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I have a file called apis.py which has many API's implemented using @api.route notation.eg:

```
    @api.route('/read', methods=['GET'])
    @api.route('/write', methods=['POST'])
```

How can get all these @api.routes paths stored somewhere? may be a hashmap / json which holds the url and the purpose of the url for eg: {"read":"/read"}. Mya be using a python script which reads all these annotations?

Comment: Yes this is duplicate!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just in case if you are using Flask, you can try this snippet:

http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/117/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this.                                                                            I have registered my flask application using   app.register_blueprint(simple_page, url_prefix='/pages') .                      How can I read this url_prefix in my python code? may be store it in a variable? or some way to make this as a global variable so that I can read it anywhere in my python code?

Comment: You can try this iteration: for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():